# CRUD em PHP e MYSQL - Excluir

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Estou com problemas em um **crud em php e myqsl**. O meu código parece não estar pegando o id para realizar as ações. O site tem uma parte administrativa na qual eu visualizo os usuários cadastrados e posso **editar, excluir e detalhar** sobre cada usuário.

Aqui está o código do **listar**, ele está associado a um html (usuarios.html). No **usuarios.html** eu pego o php via javascript - explico pq faço isso: eu quero usar o php só para realizar as ações não para exibir as ações, quero que ele fique por trás das ações. 
No listar eu tenho 3 botoes que irão realizar tais ações. Só que ele não pega o id pra fazer.

```
<?php

// exibir error
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


include 'conecta.php';

//  monta a query
$sql = "SELECT id_user, usuario, nome, sobrenome FROM  usuario";
// executa a query
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result) {

    while ($aux_query = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    { ?>


    <!-- Modal de Delete--> 
        <div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                        Deseja realmente excluir este usuário?          
                    </div>         
                    <div class="modal-footer">                
                        <a id="confirm" class="btn btn-primary"  href="excluir_user.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>">Sim</a>             
                        <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">N&atilde;o</a> 
                    </div>        
                </div>        
            </div>       
        </div> <!-- /.modal -->

        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="../assets/img/theme/perfil1.jpg">
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <input type="hidden"><?php echo'' .$aux_query["id_user"]; ?></input>
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm"><?php echo'' .$aux_query["usuario"]; ?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm"><?php echo '' .$aux_query["nome"]; ?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm"><?php echo '' .$aux_query["sobrenome"]; ?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td class="text-right">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                <a href="detalhar_user.html?id= <?php echo ''.$aux_query["id_user"];?>" class="dropdown-item" >Detalhes</a>

                <a  href="atualizar_user.html?id=<?php echo ''.$aux_query["id_user"];?>" >Editar</a>
                <button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Excluir</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr> <?php
    }

    $result->free();

} else {
    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

// fecha ponto de conexão
$conn->close();

?>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Aqui está o código do exclui_user.php e dá erro na linha 11 ($id = $_POST["id_user"];)

```
<?php 
// exibir error ini_set('display_errors',1); 
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

include 'conecta.php'; 

$id = $_POST["id_user"]; 

// monta a query 
$sql = "DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id_user = '$id'";

// executa a query 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

if ($result) { 
    echo "Usuario excluído!"; 
} else { 
    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
} 

// fecha ponto de conexão 
$conn->close(); 

?>
```

Comment: Aqui está o código do **exclui_user.php** e dá erro na linha 11 ($id = $_POST["id_user"];)


<?php

// exibir error
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


include 'conecta.php';

$id = $_POST["id_user"];

//  monta a query
$sql = "DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id_user = '$id'";

// executa a query
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result) {

    echo "Usuario excluído!";

} else {
    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

// fecha ponto de conexão
$conn->close();  

?>

Comment: Se possível clica em **[edit]** e posta o novo código. Nos comentários ele fica desorganizado. Ps.: Na pergunta você pode pressionar *Ctrl* + *K* para formatá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

A linha onde você possui o botão de exclusão está atualmente assim:

```
 <a id="confirm" class="btn btn-primary"  href="excluir_user.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>">Sim</a>
```

Não seria:

```
 <a id="confirm" class="btn btn-primary"  href="excluir_user.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>">Sim</a>
```

Note o `href="excluir_user.php?**edit**=` e o  `href="excluir_user.php?**id**=`

**RESPOSTA UPDATE 1:**

Na linha 11 do arquivo mude de:

```
$id = $_POST["id_user"];
```

para

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

**Explicação**

Quando você cria o link desta forma: `href="excluir_user.php?id=123` informando a variável pela URL (ou por Query String), do lado do PHP, no servidor, essa mesma variável só pode ser acessada via $_GET, o $_POST é para quando você envia dados do Form do HTML. Exemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="seu_script.php">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="123" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Realmente tinha esse erro. Mas foi pq eu eu peguei de um site assim para tentar de outro jeito. Só que antes estava do jeito que vc sugeriu mas não funcionava

Comment: @amandacostam9 já editei sua pergunta e editei a reposta, qualquer dúvida basta perguntar... abraço.